# celery task cannot open a model instance after passing a pk or id to the task after saving it in the django view

Tags: database, django, celery

I have a django view that creates a user then sends the user.pk to a celery task (.delay) in order to email the user and add the user to a mailing list via some API calls I don't want in the view.

After I save the new user instance `user.save()`, I send the `user.pk` to the celery task `email_user_task.delay(user.pk)`, but the celery task blows up with the error that the user does not exist.

I have tried adding a try except block in the celery task with a sleep to wait for the view to finish, which works but will cause other problems when the site is busy and tried using a manual transaction commit, but am getting other errors and feel this should work.

```
@render_to('signup.html')
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            new_user.fist_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            new_user.last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            new_user.save()
            email_user_task.delay(new_user.pk)  # this cannot get the User from the pk
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("signup_complete"))
     else:
         form = SignupForm(request=request)
     return locals()
```

This celery task blows up:

```
@task
def email_user_task(user_pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)  # this yeilds a User.DoesNotExist error
```

My first fix which works unless 5 seconds isn't enough:

```
def email_user_task(user_pk):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)  # this works I'm guessing after the view finishes
```

What am I missing? i.e. Why isn't the `new_user.save()` writing to the DB before calling the celery task?

Comment: Did you look in the database and see if the user was actually created? Also, is the celery process and the django process actually looking at the same database?

Comment: Yes, which is why the fix works adding the sleep. I also disabled and invalidated all cache locally for testing.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misread that. Have you by any chance enabled [ATOMIC_REQUESTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) in your Django app?

Comment: I think ATOMIC_REQUESTS are only in the dev django version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, try this

```
@render_to('signup.html')
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            new_user.fist_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            new_user.last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            if new_user.save():
              email_user_task.delay(new_user.pk)  # this cannot get the User from the pk
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("signup_complete"))
     else:
         form = SignupForm(request=request)
     return locals()
```

Comment: Is the `new_user` model save method here a custom one? Because django's default model save method does not really return anything. Does the task actually get kicked off?

Answer (score 1):

Since the User object is locked in the view transaction and didn't want to mess with transactions to ensure it would be saved before the celery task tries to access it, I passed all the relevant params to the celery task so it could shoot out its email.

i.e.

```
email_user_task.delay(new_user.first_name, new_user.email)
```